# Getting the old data when @click event on Laravel + Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

When I accessing the data on the method. It gives me the old data before I've done the action.

Here is my code:

**Component**

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form @submit.prevent>
            <label v-for="day in daysInWeek" v-bind:key="day.value">
                <input type="checkbox" @click="checkDays()" v-bind:value="day.value" v-model="event.daysActive">
                <span>{{ day.label }}</span>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```html
<script>
    data() {
        return {
            event: {
                eventName  : "",
                startDate  : "",
                endDate    : "",
                daysActive : [],
            },
            daysInWeek: [
                {label: 'Monday',    value: "mon"},
                {label: 'Tuesday',   value: "tue"},
                {label: 'Wednesday', value: "wed"},
                {label: 'Thursday',  value: "thu"},
                {label: 'Friday',    value: "fri"},
                {label: 'Saturday',  value: "sat"},
                {label: 'Sunday',    value: "sun"},
            ],
        };
    },

    methods : {
        checkDays() {
            console.log(this.event); // giving me the correct result
            console.log(this.event.daysActive); // giving me the data before the action
        }   
    }
</script>
```

This is the result that I'm getting

[image: First console.log]
[image: Second console.log]

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide the error typed here instead of in a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing methods() to computed()

```
<script>
    data() {
        return {
            event: {
                eventName  : "",
                startDate  : "",
                endDate    : "",
                daysActive : [],
            },
            daysInWeek: [
                {label: 'Monday',    value: "mon"},
                {label: 'Tuesday',   value: "tue"},
                {label: 'Wednesday', value: "wed"},
                {label: 'Thursday',  value: "thu"},
                {label: 'Friday',    value: "fri"},
                {label: 'Saturday',  value: "sat"},
                {label: 'Sunday',    value: "sun"},
            ],
        };
    },

    computed : {
        checkDays() {
            console.log(this.event); // giving me the correct result
            console.log(this.event.daysActive); // giving me the data before the action
        }   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How can I call that to an event?

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/edward1995/pen/YzyqPwq?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">

   <div class="container">
        <form @submit.prevent>
            <label v-for="day in daysInWeek" v-bind:key="day.value">
                <input v-if="checkDays" type="checkbox"  v-bind:value="day.value" v-model="event.daysActive">
                <span>{{ day.label }}</span>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


new Vue({
  data() {
        return {
            event: {
                eventName  : "",
                startDate  : "",
                endDate    : "",
                daysActive : [],
            },
            daysInWeek: [
                {label: 'Monday',    value: "mon"},
                {label: 'Tuesday',   value: "tue"},
                {label: 'Wednesday', value: "wed"},
                {label: 'Thursday',  value: "thu"},
                {label: 'Friday',    value: "fri"},
                {label: 'Saturday',  value: "sat"},
                {label: 'Sunday',    value: "sun"},
            ],
        };
    },

    computed : {
        checkDays() {

          return this.event.daysActive
        }   
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```